# Open floating context menu at TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have an Activity with two fields - TextView and Button. I want to open standard floating context menu (copy, paste, select all) for TextView by clicking on button. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

MayBe it can help you [Creating a floating context menu](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu) from Android API